# Get resources with hasManyThrough a model using BelongsTo

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following models:

```
User:
- id
- name

Location:
- id
- name
- region_id

table: user_location
- user_id
_ location_id
```

The user belongsToMany location through that table. I also have another model:

```
Region
- id
- name
```

I defined Region hasMany Locations.

With those relationships, how do I define a relationship between User and Region which Region will be able to find all users under all Locations associated with it?

```php
<?php 

class User extends Model
{
    public function locations() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Location', 'user_location');
    }
}

class Location extends Model
{
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_location');
    }

    public function region() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Region', 'region_id');
    }
}

class Region extends Model
{
    public function locations() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Location', 'region_id');
    }

    public function users() {
        // what am I supposed to put in here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native relationship for this case.

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship for situations like this: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class Region extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function users() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(User::class, [Location::class, 'user_location']);
    }
}
```

Comment: does it support eager loading?

Comment: Yes, it does support eager loading.